# AngularJS bind to variable from if else statement

Tags: angularjs-scope

I am not sure if my Title makes sense, but what I am looking to do is this:
I'm a noob to AngularJS and I can't seem to find the answers within the forum, but real basic for some, but for me, I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a variable {{ firstName }} in the HTML that I would like to show on the web page.

Below are the HTML, Demo.js and Data.js code.

Using console.log, I can pull the data., but I can't seem to bind to the variable firstName.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!!

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Demo">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">

    <title>AngularJS</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../WebContent/js/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $userId = 101;
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Webcontent/js/Demo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Webcontent/js/Data.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="getInfo">
    <b class="header_top_links header_top_links_small welcome_rollover mr5">Welcome {{ firstName }}</b>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo.js

```
var app = angular.module("Demo",[]);
app.controller('getInfo', function( $scope ) {

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        $scope.userId = users[i].id;
        $scope.firstName = users[i].firstName;

        if($userId == $scope.userId) {
            if($scope.userId == 102) {
                console.log("user ID: " + $scope.userId);
            } else if ($scope.userId == 101) {
                console.log("user ID: " + $scope.userId);
                console.log("user first name: " + $scope.firstName);
            } else {
                console.log("user ID: " + $scope.userId);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Data.js

```
var users = [
     {
        id: 100,
        firstName: "Guest"
     }, {
        id: 101,
        firstName: "Basick"
     }, {
         id: 102,
         firstName: "Advanced"
     }
 ];
```

Comment: Aside from your loop probably not producing the result you wanted, this code is pretty much correct. [Working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vnu410YcqSQO5cbJlIsP?p=preview). Is one of your scripts not in the right place or something?

Comment: Thx, @DarkFalcon for the quick response. My page was caching reason why the variable wasn't showing. It's working now.